# Problems with user login after artifactory upgrade (5.5.1->6.23.13)

Tags: artifactory

I'm trying to upgrade an old artifactory (OSS) installation from version 5.5.1 to 6.23.13 on RHEL.  The DB is postgres.

Have copied the DB and filesystem from production (running 5.5.1) to a test installation (running 6.23.13).

The test implementation appears to work, except for a problem with user permissions, which don't appear to be picked up as expected in the new system.

I note that in 5.5.1, the users appear in a 'users' table in Postgres.  However, in the 6.23.13 version, this table is being ignored and users are being populated into an 'access_users' table instead.

The users authenticate with LDAP (that part is working) but when logged in, do not get any of their old groups and permissions.

I'm not very familiar with artifactory, so any pointers on where to look to get to the bottom of this appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be expected because Artifactory 5.5.1 is kind of old and Artifactory 6.23.13 is new with a different schema. What I need to understand is how the migration was done?

Comment: You need to follow the upgrade procedure documented here - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Upgrading+Artifactory

Comment: Migration was done by creating a new VM with the updated (6.x version), then pointing it at a clone of the database from the 5.x version.Is this the correct procedure, or does something more specific need to be done to handle the migration to a different schema in the new version?